# Is there a way to extend WP_query so Custom Post Types can have properties?

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, variables

Having trouble finding info on this. When working with lots of metadata/custom fields, I would really prefer to simplify getting the meta data inside of templates instead of using `get_post_meta` and instead keep the setting up of that data in the back-end where it belongs to keep my templates clean and easier to work with.

Is there a way to do this?

```php
<p><?php echo $something->meta_field_name ?></p>
```

This would be similar to how you can do things like `$post->ID` or `$post->post_parent` that are in WordPress core, except it would be for custom post types and custom fields. If this is not possible, I guess the next question would be, why?

---

*Edit:* Since I've seen this mentioned several times in responses, when writing PHP like this you have to *escape the output*, which I do. I left out the escaping for brevity, but for anyone new to it, here's how I would typically write this (and thanks to @fuxia for the solution to my original question).

Escaping (with the solution) for WordPress:

```php
<p id="text-<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_name) ?>"><?php echo esc_html($post->meta_key_name) ?></p>
```

And if you're outputting to a class:

```php
<p class="text-<?php echo sanitize_html_class($post->post_title) ?>">Clean Class</p>
```

I typically wouldn't use `post_title` but using it as an example as `sanitize_html_class` will remove white space and only keep alphanumeric characters, underscores and dashes.

If outputting things like JSON-LD, you can combine escaping:

```json
"@id": "<?php echo esc_js(esc_url($link)) ?>#<?php echo esc_js($post->post_name) ?>",
"name": "<?php echo esc_js($post->post_title) ?>"
```

Comment: I believe the reason this isn't possible is because `post_meta` is in a separate table, whereas the examples you cited are part of the `posts` table, so when you retrieve a post, data like `id` and `post_parent` or `guid` are returned in that row, but when retrieving `post_meta` you're using the ID to run a secondary DB call to a different table.  I guess it could be done by writing a custom function, but I really don't see why that would be necessary.

Comment: note that there is no escaping in your example, and there are no opportunities for filters to run. This also won't work if there is more than one meta with that key ( meta keys are not unique ). There may be plugin compatibility issues with this. Custom post types are just post types, the same as the `page` or `post` type etc, they're stored the same way and handled the same way ( except that posts have rewrite rules and templates for date archives )

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to brief. `<p><?php echo esc_html($something->meta_field_name) ?></p>

Comment: I have updated my post with the solution and showing how I escape output, for those who are new to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting meta data from a `WP_Post` object is already possible. Just write:

```
echo $post->your_meta_key;
```

This will call `get_post_meta( $this->ID, $your_meta_key, true )` behind the scenes.

See the documentation and the source code for [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/).

This works also with instances of `WP_User`, but not with `WP_Comment` as far as I know.

Don't forget to escape the output!

Comment: I didn't realize that. This will come in handy.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me... -_- I don't believe I've seen this anywhere. Feel like stabbing my computer right now. Well, at least it works. Guess I'll be spending the next 2 days rewriting my templates. Thank you!

Comment: Completely forgot about `__get`, nice to know that WordPress uses magic methods, now I wonder where else did they use them. WordPress has some hidden gems that its a shame that they don't document them better.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast `WP_User` is another example. I have updated my answer.

Comment: virtual -1 for the property way. Some day in 2030 there will be a new field in the post object and it will collide with your meta name. Don't use magic methods unless you must because it makes the code less readable.